# Get rid of scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am creating a website and I want to put several fixed-type links in the bottom. When you click to one of these links you go one-picture down to the page to the next image and so on. And if you scroll down, you go down to that picture as well. BUT I do want to get rid of the Scroll bars. It means you can go down when you scroll but you can't see where exactly you are on that page.

Comment: Why would you want to do this to your users? That doesn't sound like a very friendly user experience.

Comment: It looks awesome. It sounds great. You don't see where you are on the page in the scroll bar because you don't have it, but you see where you    are in the active link.

Comment: That doesn't sound awesome. Scroll bars are a consistent and expected experience in the browser. I want to know where I am in a page. Most users do. Thinking it "looks awesome" isn't really a great defence for braking away from commonly accepted UI paradigms. You really shouldn't mess with this stuff.

Comment: I understand it, but no scroll bar on the main page is not a big deal, even if users will not scroll down, it will be only to sign in and sign up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do: I would have an all encompassing HTML container then move child content accordingly based on your user events. For example, onClick of one of your 'fixed-type' links as well as onScroll of the window you could trigger the same event, essentially.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content1"></div>
    <div id="content2"></div>
    <div id="content3"></div>
    <div id="content4"></div>

    <div id="links">
        <a href="0" class="contentLink">link 1</a> | 
        <a href="1" class="contentLink">link 2</a> | 
        <a href="2" class="contentLink">link 3</a> | 
        <a href="3" class="contentLink">link 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container, #content1, #content2, #content3, #content4 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
#content1 { top: 0%; background: green; }
#content2 { top: 100%; background: red; }
#content3 { top: 200%; background: orange; }
#content4 { top: 300%; background: purple; }

#links {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; left: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var currentPos = 0,
        scrollDirection;

    $(".contentLink").click(function(evt) {
        // prevent default behavior to avoid page refresh
        evt.preventDefault();

        // get the desired position
        newPos = $(this).attr("href");

        // if the current position is less than the desired position
        // move content up, if it's greater than - move it down
        // do nothing if they're equal
        if (newPos > currentPos) {
            $("#content1, #content2, #content3, #content4").animate({
                top: "-=" + ((newPos-currentPos) * 100) + "%" 
            }, 1000);        
        } else if (newPos < currentPos) {
            $("#content1, #content2, #content3, #content4").animate({
                top: "+=" + ((currentPos-newPos) * 100) + "%" 
            }, 1000);  
        }

        // reset currentPos accordingly
        currentPos = newPos;
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works great with hidden scroll, but it doesn't scroll down.

Comment: how do you mean? are you trying to have a large page with scrollable content in addition to a 'hidden scroll' portion of the page?

Comment: not a large page. just three links where each of them is 100% lower than another one.

Comment: so you'd like to be able to scroll the page as well as have the links trigger a scroll, and without the scrollbar?

Comment: yes, is it possible to do?

Comment: not if you want to remove the scrollbar in a cross-browser compatible way. however, if you can implement your own scrollTo function and you're only concerned with webkit browsers (like in the case of targeting iOS and Android) you can add ::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } to your stylesheet and everything should behave as normal but the scrollbar won't appear. again, this is only valid on webkit browsers.

Comment: any upvotes/question answered would be appreciated. thanks! :)